# Can I add 'import pandas' to the %pylab magic?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Every jupyter notebook I write has the same first two lines:

```
%pylab inline
import pandas
```

How can I add pandas to pylab's imports, so that I no longer need to import it separately.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `pip install pandas`?

Comment: Yep, pandas imports just fine, but what I'd like to do is to import pandas whenever I run '%pylab inline'

Comment: Oh! I see, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%pylab` makes the following imports to the interactive Ipython session: (http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pylab)

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab, mlab, pyplot
np = numpy
plt = pyplot

from IPython.display import display
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize, getfigs

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

No import of `pandas` exists in `%pylab`. Unless you are looking to tweak the `IPython` source (which would affect the robustness of your implementation), the most simplest way is to do:

```
%load myimports.py
```

where `myimports.py` local file contains:

```
%pylab inline
import pandas
```

Disclaimer: This is just one of the ways, there could be other ways as well.

Comment: Yeah, your myimports solution works for me. I was willing to tweak the ipython source, but your way seems cleaner.